# Laravel 5.2 and Dropbox

Tags: laravel, dropbox

решил использовать dropbox как хранилище файлов, создал сервис провайдер как в доках все норм put,get,. создаю и открываю файлы, теперь есть нужда по пути например `Route::get('/file/{filename}','FileController@getFileByName');`
отдавать файл не показывая путь до самого файла. 
через локальный диск можно было

```
$file = Storage::url('file.txt'); 
return response()->download($file);
```

по копался в доках дропбокса и нашел методы `createTemporaryDirectLink` и `createShareableLink` но они не дают ссылку на файл для скачивания а показывают превью ну и там же кнопка скачать мне это не подходит так как я хочу отдавать файлы не показывая ссылку на сам файл 
пока не могу найти решение по этому обращаюсь тут за помощью

Answer (score 0):

А почему не использовать [бридж](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Dropbox)? Там же вроде доступен метод по скачиванию файла (getFile($path, $outStream, $rev = null))

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ) но на тот момент обошелся локальным хранилищем